# c# script for .dbf import

Tags: c#, xls, dbf

Ive had the question to make something, where customer can import a .dbf file. This file contains products with prices etc. After importing that file, he wants to export the products with a promotion date from and till. So i was thinking: Make a query that only takes the lines where promodate is not null. 
So i was thinking to make something with a basic GUI, with a datagrid and 2 buttons: import and export.

Now, as im not experienced with .dbf files, is it A) possible to import it in a local sql database/c# grid? And B) is it possible to import it as dbf and export it to xls/xlsx?

Anyone some advice? Is c# a good option for this?

Don't really know where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check http://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnetdbf/ and http://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnetdbf.enumerable/

Answer (score 0):

With C# you can use this [**library FAST DBF**](http://fastdbf.codeplex.com/) to read/write your dbf files. I prefer to use **powershell** when i need file conversion, [**here**](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/48f71b47-a0a8-40c8-b260-271ac2396556/how-to-read-dbf-files-using-powerhsell) there is a powershell example.

Furthermore, in **powershell** is posible create an **Excel object** to do any type of Excel import/export operation, **[example is here](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/d41565f1-37ef-43cb-9462-a08cd5a610e2)**.